# Is dirtycow unharmful without shell access?

Tags: linux, dirty-cow, kernel-patch-protection

Let's say have a linux server to which only I have shell access and all other users shells are disabled. Is there any reason to be preoccupied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dirty cow does not need shell access. It only needs the ability to execute own software. This can for example also be done by using a security problem in a web application to upload and execute remote code.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer in my opinion:

You could execute dirtycow exploit if you have:

shell access;
RCE in web server or anything else;
a social engineered customer support;
etc

You should fully understand or at least partially understand how the exploit works to understand it's possibilities of being executed. 
Read up on it at: github.com/dirtycow/

Multiple versions of it hosted on that account.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is more complete. All you have added to the other answer was "a social engineered customer support, etc."